# No sound from Clevo computer running Debian 12

Tags: linux, audio, debian, kde-plasma-5

I have a Clevo PD70SND-G, fresh from China. Installed Debian 12 Bookworm (dual boot with Windows 10 Pro). There is no sound. Switching to Windows, I have verified it is not defective hardware. Debian detects the sound hardware and loads the drivers. Tried playing an audio file, the volume controls flash as if it is attempting to send the audio to the speakers. Tried plugging in a headset, still no sound. Please help.

```
Wed Jan 31 - 13:32:22 > [username] > ~ >
 1/85/0 $ neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          [username]@ComputerName-Linux-Debian
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       --------------------------
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: PD5x_7xSNC_SND_SNE
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.1.0-17-amd64
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 1 min
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 2422 (dpkg)
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1080
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Plasma 5.27.5
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: KWin
  `Y$$                        Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3]
   `Y$$.                      Icons: [Plasma], breeze [GTK2/3]
     `$$b.                    Terminal: konsole
       `Y$$b.                 CPU: Intel i9-14900HX (32) @ 2.200GHz
          `"Y$b._             GPU: Intel Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics
              `"""            GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile
                              Memory: 2733MiB / 64000MiB
```

```
Wed Jan 31 - 11:59:39 > [username] > ~ >
 19/55/0 $ inxi -Fxz
 ...
 udio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: CLEVO/KAPOK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 0000:01:00.1
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-17-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 status: active
...
```

```
Wed Jan 31 - 12:20:22 > [username] > ~ >
 20/55/0 $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
Wed Jan 31 - 12:39:13 > [username] > ~ >
21/56/0 $ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0x6205230000 irq 225
1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                     HDA NVidia at 0x77000000 irq 17

Wed Jan 31 - 19:19:18 > [username] > ~ >
8/92/0 $ systemctl status --user pipewire.service
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-31 19:18:14 EST; 1min 22s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
  Main PID: 6709 (pipewire)
     Tasks: 2 (limit: 76722)
    Memory: 3.8M
       CPU: 44ms
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
            └─6709 /usr/bin/pipewire

Jan 31 19:18:14 ComputerName-Linux-Debian systemd[1741]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.
```

```
Wed Jan 31 - 19:19:36 > [username] > ~ >
 9/93/0 $ systemctl status --user wireplumber.service
● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-31 19:19:18 EST; 52s ago
   Main PID: 6740 (wireplumber)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 76722)
     Memory: 7.8M
        CPU: 164ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/wireplumber.service
             └─6740 /usr/bin/wireplumber

Jan 31 19:19:18 ComputerName-Linux-Debian systemd[1741]: Started wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager.
Jan 31 19:19:18 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: Failed to set scheduler settings: Operation not permitted
Jan 31 19:19:18 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: SPA handle 'api.libcamera.enum.manager' could not be loaded; is it installed?
Jan 31 19:19:18 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: PipeWire's libcamera SPA missing or broken. libcamera not supported.
Jan 31 19:19:19 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: Trying to use legacy bluez5 API for LE Audio - only A2DP will be supported. Please upgrade bluez5.
Jan 31 19:19:19 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x55e0903dbc80> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.po>
lines 1-16/16 (END)...skipping...
● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-31 19:19:18 EST; 52s ago
   Main PID: 6740 (wireplumber)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 76722)
     Memory: 7.8M
        CPU: 164ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/wireplumber.service
             └─6740 /usr/bin/wireplumber

Jan 31 19:19:18 ComputerName-Linux-Debian systemd[1741]: Started wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager.
Jan 31 19:19:18 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: Failed to set scheduler settings: Operation not permitted
Jan 31 19:19:18 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: SPA handle 'api.libcamera.enum.manager' could not be loaded; is it installed?
Jan 31 19:19:18 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: PipeWire's libcamera SPA missing or broken. libcamera not supported.
Jan 31 19:19:19 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: Trying to use legacy bluez5 API for LE Audio - only A2DP will be supported. Please upgrade bluez5.
Jan 31 19:19:19 ComputerName-Linux-Debian wireplumber[6740]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x55e0903dbc80> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
```

Comment: If I had to guess I would say it's because the hardware is too new :). Occasionally it needs time to catch up with the companion chips and architecture of the brand new Intel generation. HDMI/DP audio should work with the proper Nvidia driver installed but the integrated audio chipset, not the one ion the graphics cards may need a patch until the full support is added to kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar hardware.

For now, and for you, the solution would be to pass the following option in your modprobe config. Not sure where that resides on Debian, on Arch it is in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=clevo-p950
```

This works great for me for up until kernel series 6.7, and so I am still using series 6.6, and I can see you are using 6.1, so it should all be good for a while for you.

Comment: Followed up with `sudo update-initramfs -u`, a reboot, and it works! Thanks.